# How can I implement a Refresh button for a WebView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add a button to the top navigation bar that will reload the webview on screen. I have tried everything tthat I could find online.

Expecting when clicking the reload button it reloads the webview but I am new to SwiftUi and I am struggling to grasp this concept and also not sure if this is achievable in SwiftUi yet.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                TabView {
                    WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://website.com/")!))
                        .tabItem {
                            Image("first")
                            Text("Map")
                                .navigationBarTitle("PPM", displayMode: .inline)
                                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    Button("Reload") {

                                })
                    }.tag(0)
                    WebView2(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://website.com/")!))
                        .tabItem {
                            Image("second")
                            Text("Nests")
                                .navigationBarTitle("PPM", displayMode: .inline)
                    }.tag(1)
                    WebView3(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://https://website.com/")!))
                        .tabItem {
                            Image("stats")
                            Text("Map Stats")
                                .navigationBarTitle("PPM", displayMode: .inline)
                    }.tag(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your WebView components?

Comment: Did you find a way to make this work?? It is so hard to find a resource on this :(

Comment: did you find an answer? @Ohsik